# App crashes on other devices but work perfectly on my device

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I have made an android app that find atm, banks around your current location or custom location. but when I click on the button the app crashes on other devices not on my device

this is My logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                     Process: com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2, PID: 27580java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2.StartActivity.onClick(StartActivity.java:158)
                                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the layout file activity_start.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ATM"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Airport"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bank"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Bus Station"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Doctor"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hospital"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find new location"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="54dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Church"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gym"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="School"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Park"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button12"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bar"
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mosque"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="Enter prefered radius between 2 - 50 km"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="Enter location eg. sector-55,Noida/Delhi"/>

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set to Current Location"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

manifestfile.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2">



        <permission
            android:name="com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name1"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".Splashscreen">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".StartActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".PlaceDetailsActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name=".PlaceDetails" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBcL4XaHzcJCslvOq5Q9jfT2XIXf3TmVIo"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

StartActivity.java

```
package com.example.udaygarg.locationplacedetailsv2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class StartActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, LocationListener {

    Button bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9, bt10, bt11, bt12, bt13, bt14;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    int radius = 2;
    EditText et1, et2;
    double latitude, longitude;
    Intent in;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bt4.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        bt5.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        bt6.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        bt7.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        bt8.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        bt9.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        bt10.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        bt11.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        bt12.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt13= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        bt13.setOnClickListener(this);

        bt14= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        bt14.setOnClickListener(this);




        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {


            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests

                sendquerydata("atm", radius, latitude, longitude);

            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                showAlertDialog(StartActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection. Connect to the internet", false);
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button8) {
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                String address = et2.getText().toString();
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                    longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                }
                sendquerydata("", 2, latitude, longitude);
            }
            else{
                showAlertDialog(StartActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection. Connect to the internet", false);
            }


        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button7) {



                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location location;
                location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                sendquerydata("", 2, latitude, longitude);

            }
```

the app crashes on clicking button 7 and 8. please help with this, ty
ps: my first time asking a question here

Comment: Taking a look into it. In the future, please only include code that is relevant to your question to prevent having to sift through textblocks

Comment: Did you try to debug the code ?

Comment: @BR89 ok, I will keep that in mind

Comment: @F.sh yes I have tried, app crashes in StartActivity.java on button 8,        
  if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    latitude =    addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                    longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                }

Comment: Put the IF inside the try above it, maybe the assignment to addresses is not working well inside the try, so you have null addresses and here you are getting the exception

Comment: thx @F.sh its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the IF inside the Try above it, maybe the assignment to addresses is not working well inside the Try, so you have null addresses and here you are getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

Write a seperate function for block button 7 and button 8 and then check the permissions if not granted call requestPermissions and if user grant it call the function you privously written and if you have already granted the permission run the function immediately . Be aware you don't need check the permissions before api 23 write a if statement to check whether the SDK_INT is upper than 23 or not